# Sql group by: How to get the value that appears most often

Tags: sql

I have a table

```
Id1   Id2
1     2
1     2
1     3
1     4
1     4
1     4
2     2
2     3
2     3
```

I need the next result(maximum count of each group by id1 id2)

```
1  4
2  3
```

EDIT:

```
Id1   Id2
1     10
1     10
1     5
1     2
1     2
1     2
2     20
2     6
2     6
```

I need the next result(maximum count of each group by id1 id2)

```
1  2
2  6
```

**Edit:** (from Stefan Steinegger)

The query should return each id1 with the id2 that appears most often in combination. (Hope this helps to understand the question.)

Comment: What's the maximum count? what do the number 1/4 and 2/3 mean?

Comment: And what's the *next result"?

Comment: first you should try some query and then post it if u didn't get. The thing is u should try first.

Comment: The edit is confusing. Why is not 10/20 selected if you want `max`?

Comment: I see. it's 2 and 6 because they appear the most as Id2 in combination with the id1.

Comment: I think, OP want to show one id2 for each id1 which has appeared most.

Comment: Downvote reasons: 1st. it's unclear what you are asking. I'm note voting to close yet since I want to give you a chance to edit your question. 2nd. This question shows no effort what so ever to try and find the answer yourself.

Comment: **Please stop complaining about this question**. It is a very good question with a very interesting SQL problem. It only needs some rephrasing. We already know what the OP actually wants to do, so help him to find better words and stop down-voting.

Comment: @StefanSteinegger: I disagree. This question is poorly represented, shows no effort what so ever to find a solution by the OP and missing relevant information such as the RDBMS. I would say it deserves the downvotes.

Answer (score 4):

Try this [Sql demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c9d4d/2)

```
select test_2.Id1,test_3.Id2 from 
     ( select Id1,MAX(countval)as val from
               (select Id1,count(Id2 ) as countval,Id2  from test
                group by Id2 ,Id1) as test_1 
       group by Id1) as test_2 
         inner join 
               (select Id1,count(Id2) as countval,Id2 from test
               group by Id2,Id1) as test_3
                on test_3.countval=test_2.val and test_2.Id1= test_3.Id1
```

Comment: Where is `y` from `y.Id1`? Also not sure what `count([desc])` does, but it might just be a dbms thing.

Comment: Seems to be working better now. Although this is not a pretty sight, the expected results are correct +1

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
SELECT id1,
       id2
FROM   (SELECT *,
               row_number()
                 OVER (
                   partition BY id1
                   ORDER BY cnt DESC) [rn]
        FROM   (SELECT *,
                       COUNT(*)
                         OVER (
                           partition BY id1, id2) AS [cnt]
                FROM   @table) t) t1
WHERE  rn = 1
```

Comment: This works in MS Sql (and perhaps MySql?) anyway. I'm impressed by the complexity :) Wonder if it has to be that complex

Comment: I think it has to be that complex. You want to have the value that appears the most frequently. There is no out-of-the-box SQL syntax for. It would be even more complex with "normal" query syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
create table id
(
id1 int,
id2 int)

insert into id values(1,2)
insert into id values(1,2)
insert into id values(1,3)
insert into id values(1,4)
insert into id values(1,4)
insert into id values(1,4)
insert into id values(2,2)
insert into id values(2,3)
insert into id values(2,3)


select id1,max(id2) as 'maxcount'
from id
group by id1

drop table id
```

Output:

```
id1 maxcount
1   4
2   3
```

Comment: We already had this (see deleted answers). It's not what he wants.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sqlfiddle.com to test.

Build your schema:

```
create table test (id1 number, id2 number);
insert into test values (1, 2);
insert into test values (1, 3);
insert into test values (1, 3);
insert into test values (1, 4);
insert into test values (1, 4);
insert into test values (1, 4);
insert into test values (2, 2);
insert into test values (2, 3);
insert into test values (2, 3);
select test.*, rowid from test;
```

And run your SQL:

```
SELECT id1, max(id2) max
FROM test
GROUP BY id1;
```

This was your first and original post. You can do the same for de EDITED part.

Result:

```
ID1 MAX
1   4
2   3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use HAVING function on a subquery which count number of id2.

Example:

```
SELECT id1, id2
FROM
  (SELECT id1, id2, count(id2) as groupCount
  FROM table
  GROUP BY id1, id2) as sub
GROUP BY id1
HAVING max(groupCount)
```

Answer (score 0):

Following answers are based on Standard SQL, most DBMSes should support them.

Using Windowed Aggregate Functions:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
 (
   SELECT id1, id2, COUNT(*) AS CNT,
      RANK() -- maximum count per id1 gets rank 1
      OVER (PARTITION BY id1
            ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS maxCnt
   FROM test
   GROUP BY id1, id2
 ) AS dt
WHERE CNT = maxCnt
```

What do you want to return when there are multiple values with the same max count? RANK returns all of them, change it to ROW_NUMBER to get only one.

Next version uses old-style SQL which should be supported by every DBMS:

```
SELECT id1, id2, COUNT(*) AS CNT
FROM test AS t1
GROUP BY id1, id2
HAVING COUNT(*) = 
 ( SELECT MAX(CNT) 
   FROM
    (
      SELECT id1, id2, COUNT(*) AS CNT
      FROM test
      GROUP BY id1, id2
    )  AS t2
   WHERE t1.id1 = t2.id1
 )
```

This will return **all** values with the max count, getting just one of them is way more complicated.

If you got luck your DBMS supports `WITH`, so you have to write the aggregate only once (but this might only look better and the optimizer might actually run it similar to the previous query):

```
WITH cte AS
 (
   SELECT id1, id2, COUNT(*) AS CNT
   FROM test
   GROUP BY id1, id2
 ) 
SELECT *
FROM cte AS t1
WHERE CNT = 
 ( SELECT MAX(CNT) 
   FROM cte AS t2
   WHERE t1.id1 = t2.id1
 )
```